# get rid of LogCat

Tags: android

I am Using the newest version of eclipse JUNO to do android programming. can anybody tell me to how to get rid of LogCat? I dont have the option display LogCat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

remove logcat:

[image: click 'x']

bring logcat back: 
step 1 -

[image: click 'other']

step 2 -

[image: click ok]

Comment: Pictures are worth a thousand words.